# Speech to Text Watson interrupt by silence

Tags: python, speech-to-text, watson

We are using the API Sessionless and python, we have put the 'continue:True' parameter like this:

def make_completed_audio_request(url, API_name=None, language=None, time=None):

```
username, password, endpoint, lan=select_voice_api(name=API_name, language=language)
audio = get_complete_audio(url, api_name=API_name, time=time)
endpoint=get_post_endpoint(url=endpoint, api_name=API_name)
if audio:
    list_audio=get_speakers_by_audio(audio[1].name)
    headers={'content-type': audio[2]}
    params = {'model': lan,
      'continuous':True,
              'timestamps': True}
    if language and (API_name == 'watson' or API_name == 'WATSON'):
        print 'enviando request'
        response = requests.post(url=endpoint, auth=(username, password), 
            params=params, data=audio[1], headers=headers)
        print 'cladificando error'
        error_clasifier(code=response.status_code)
    else:
        response = requests.post(url=endpoint, auth=(username, password), 
            params=params, data=audio[1], headers=headers)
        error_clasifier(code=response.status_code)
    if response:
    return response, list_audio, True, None
else:
    return None, None, False, None
```

But it still does not work, it cuts the transcription in the first silence it founds

What am I doing wrong? is there another way to send it to the API?

Comment: There are many other APIs which are more accurate and recognize long files.

Comment: Thank for the comment @NikolayShmyrev , but we decided to use watson for the kewywords feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using watson_developer_cloud API. Its easy to use and what is more important - it works. Here is the code sample:

```
import json

from os.path import join, dirname

from watson_developer_cloud import SpeechToTextV1

speech_to_text = SpeechToTextV1(
    username="yourusername",
    password="yourpassword",
    x_watson_learning_opt_out=False)

with open(join(dirname(__file__), 'test.wav'), 'rb') as audio_file:

    data = json.dumps(speech_to_text.recognize(audio_file, content_type='audio/wav',  word_confidence=True, continuous=True, word_alternatives_threshold=0, max_alternatives=10))
```